# Simplest "PIVOT" without Aggregation or Joins

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have the most basic need to "pivot" rows into separate columns but cannot find a simple solution after an hour of searching.

My data looks like this:

```
providernumber txnmy_cd
001            1234
001            4321
001            3214
```

I need it to display like this:

```
providernumber       txnmy_cd1, txnmy_cd2, txnmy_cd3
001                  1234       4321       3214
```

I've tried several methods, but all the examples I'm seeing here have aggregate functions and/or joins and seem way overkill for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I'm sorry.  SQL/SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you don't need DYNAMIC SQL

**Example**

```
Select *
 From  (
        Select [providernumber]
              ,Value = [txnmy_cd]
              ,Item = 'txnmy_cd'+ convert(varchar(25),row_number() over ( Partition By [providernumber] order by  (Select null) ) )
         From  YourTable
       ) src
 Pivot ( max(Value) for Item in ( [txnmy_cd1],[txnmy_cd2],[txnmy_cd3] ) ) pvt
```

**Returns**

```
providernumber  txnmy_cd1   txnmy_cd2   txnmy_cd3
1               1234        4321        3214
```

Comment: Thanks John!  Query works great but I get all NULLS for values in my txnmy_cd1, txnmy_cd2, & txnmy_cd3 columns.  What am I missing?

Comment: @user3406654 I don't understand ALL nulls or scattered ?

Comment: All NULLS...every value is nulls.  I probably just need to write an 'ISNULL' somewhere to handle them.  ???

Comment: Many of my providers do not have taxonomy codes but I still need to list them.  I hope that makes sense.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user3406654 If ALL nulls then somthing else is wrong.  If you do have values, then you can trap with an ISNULL.    https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=75353a17567038b9e0fedeac48f32842

Comment: @user3406654  Sorry wrong link  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=c9ef05d2cd0fe41fea81880436d1b400

Comment: @user3406654 I know you are new, but if you found this to be helpful, feel free to ACCEPT the answer

Comment: Thank you John.  Something else is wrong either with my data or my query.  Now instead of NULL values, I get blanks, but still not actual txnmy_cd1 values that I see in my table.  ???  I appreciate your help.  The structure is exactly what I need but I have to figure out why the data isn't showing.

Comment: The only difference I can see is that you set 'providernumber' as VARCHAR and in my data 'providernumber' is INT.

Comment: @user3406654 Would not make a difference.  I choose varchar because in your sample data you have 001 not just 1.     The blank are now from the ISNULL(...) portion added in the last dbFiddle.  This is optional.    This is a simple pivot, I suspect there is something that I am not understanding about your data.   As a test, add a filter like  ...  FROM YOURTABLE WHERE providernumber<=10   (or some reasonable number)